# Javascript map show error message if undefined instead of breaking

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue where the console is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: myData.names is undefined
```

and here is the code:

```
var myvar = myData.names.map(function (value) {
     return [value.name, 1];
});
```

When I get this error the code just breaks so the rest of the code will stop working.

What can I do so that the user gets an alert instead and the code doesn't break the whole of the page?

Comment: use a try catch block.

Comment: The error you get is because there is no names in your myData. Try to check myData that it contains "names".

Comment: use if(myData.names.length>0) in your code

Comment: @DurgpalSingh that would still result in an error.

Comment: ok then check myData is empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `myData` is not `undefined` or put your code in `try catch block`

```
try{
    if(myData && myData.names){

            var myvar = myData.names.map(function (value) {
                return [value.name, 1];
            });

      }
   }
     catch(ex){
        console.log(ex.toString();
    }
```

Comment: They'll also have to check that the property `names` also exists on the `myData` variable.

Comment: `if(myData && myData.names){` would make sense.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes you are right but i guess we can't use it in same line as if `myData` is `undefined` `myData.names` will still throw error.

Comment: @Leopard you can because if myData doesn't exist it will exit the condition before trying to evaluate the second condition.

Comment: @Leopard `&&` is a short circuit operator, It wont proceed evaluating expressions after finding a falsy value.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, got it will edit my asnwer.

Comment: It's giving me error: SyntaxError: catch without try

Comment: You may have one missing parenthesis.